# Python getting full path to working zip file

Tags: python, file, file-io, zip

I have a zipfile object:

```
docx_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(path)
```

I want to access the full path of that zip file in order to pass that path to `ImageTk` Image object, so I need the path to that file.

```
image = Image.open(PATH_TO_IMAGE)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

So I ask: How can I get PATH_TO_IMAGE ?

One method optional is to extract it to the current working directory and give it the new path (the file name), but I was wondering if there is an option to get the full path straight from the zip archive.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
import os.path
docx_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(path)
print os.path.dirname(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `zipfile` allows for this. At least I can't find anything in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist), but there is a workaround. You can create a `ZipInfo` object from your ZipFile, which will hold the information you want:

```
import zipfile
import os

docx_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_path)
docx_info = docx_zip.getinfo(name_of_image_in_zip)
path_to_image = os.path.abspath(docx_info.filename)
# or get all paths:
docx_name_list = docx_zip.infolist()
paths_to_images = [os.path.abspath(x.filename) for x in docx_name_list]
```

I hope this helps.